# Authenticated AWS user trouble in Cloudberry S3 Explorer Pro

Tags: cloudberry

When setting up Access Manager (IAM) in S3 Explorer Pro.
I am warned about two of my (Amazon S3) Authenticated AWS users, here is a warning,

```
User. arn:aws:iam;:711586701422:user/mike.drunkbeater is not
authorized to perform: iam:ListGroups on resource::
arn:aws:iam::711586701422;group/`enter code here`
```

Where might the problem be originating? With the Authenticated AWS user at the AWS control panel or a Cloudberry S3 Explorer Pro setting I have wrong? I am successfully performing backups with Cloudberry Backup VM Edition and have used the “trouble users” in the past successfully.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what cloudberry S3 explorer is but I see that you have a typo in:

`arn:aws:iam::711586701422**;**group/`

In case you don't see it, you have a semi-colon, where should be a colon.

HTH.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely tyope! CloudBerry Explorer (cloudberrylab.com/explorer) is tool to manage files in S3. It comes with IAM policy configuration feature.